# How to select a newest row from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT  
    Segment_ID = Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326) as the_geom,
    a.NumAll,
    a.AverageDailyIntens,
    a.AverageDailyIntensCar,
    a.Loading   
FROM dbo.Segment_ID
RIGHT JOIN Road  ON Segment_ID.Road_ID = Road.Road_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
outer apply (select top 1 Intensity.NumAll,Intensity.AverageDailyIntens,Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar,Intensity.Loading   
from Intensity 
         where Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Intensity.Segment_ID
         ORDER BY Intensity.NumAll) a
```

It works fine but does not what I want. It gives me FIRST row from `Intensity` with `Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Intensity.Segment_ID` but I want take latest row.

In table `Intensity` I have date columns with dates like this `2009-02-20 15:00:00.000`.
How can I take row to needed `Segment_ID` with latest date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `ORDER BY` clause to sort by your date column in descending order:

```
outer apply (
   select top 1
          Intensity.NumAll
        , Intensity.AverageDailyIntens
        , Intensity.AverageDailyIntensCar
        , Intensity.Loading   
   from Intensity 
   where  Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Intensity.Segment_ID
   ORDER BY Intensity.your_date_field DESC
   ) a
```